# Java SAML2 SSO client

Tags: java, security, saml, saml-2.0

I want to connect to a SAML2 SSO identity provider with java so that I can then connect to some web endpoints and make authenticated requests.

I looked at the Java libraries at https://github.com/onelogin but they appear to be libraries for providing SAML authentication, as opposed to connecting to SAML as a client.

Does anyone know of any Java libraries for this. With examples would be great as I am a beginner with SAML2.

Comment: In general, handling SAML message is different from implementing a SAMLv2 compliant service provider. If you have a web app, it might be worth looking at Spring Security SAML extension. IMHO it's the most complete SAMLv2 service provider implementation.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can understand, The OneLogin lib should do what you want. It will have your Java application act as a Service Provider and make authentication requests.

[Spring SAML](https://projects.spring.io/spring-security-saml/) is another alternative and [Lastpass](https://github.com/lastpass/saml-sdk-java) has yet another alternative

You could also do SAML on a more low level using OpenSAML, but for a simple use-case the libs above will do the trick.

To get a feel for SAML I can hint for my book, [A Guide to OpenSAML](https://blog.samlsecurity.com/a-guide-to-opensamlv3.html). It explains SAML and how to do user authentication using OpenSAML. Again I recommend the libs above, but the book can be good to get a understanding of SAML.

Comment: Nice answer. I like the sound of Spring since I have used it before. Do you have a link to a example with spring.

Comment: No sorry, but it shouldn't be hard to find. Good luck! Please mark the answer as correct if you consider your question answered